# BroadcastReceiver works only once

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call

I have a class that extends BroadcastReceiver. This class detects outgoing calls, especially tells me the start and end time of the call. The point is that when I run the application the first time it works without problem and with the accompanying toast tell me the status of the call. The point is that when I make a new call seconds or minutes after the application closes abruptly. I set the permissions on the respective manifest. The class code is is next:

```
 public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Context mContext;
    private Intent mIntent;
    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;
    private String TAG="PhoneStateListener";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        mIntent = intent;
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;
        tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
    }

    private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
                // phone ringing
                Log.i(TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                // active
                Log.i(TAG, "OFFHOOK");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Llamada saliente repicando", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                isPhoneCalling = true;
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
                // run when class initial and phone call ended,
                // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                Log.i(TAG, "IDLE");
                if (isPhoneCalling) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "TERMINO LA LLAMADA =D");
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Llamada saliente finalizada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    isPhoneCalling = false;
                }

            }
    }

    };

}
```

In the manifest I have the following:

```
    <receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReceiver">   
            <intent-filter>                
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>   

   <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

The error is that from the second run the application ends abruptly. I was unable to determine the error. Any help is appreciated. Greetings.

Comment: Add the logcat error log in question.

Comment: The lograr categoría say: 04-10 13:00:36.436: W/dalvikvm(8248): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f042a0)
04-10 13:00:36.466: E/AndroidRuntime(8248): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 13:00:36.466: E/AndroidRuntime(8248): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 13:00:36.466: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
04-10 13:00:36.466: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
04-10 13:00:36.466: E/AndroidRuntime(8248):  at com.androideity.systemservices.IncomingCall$1.onCallStateChanged(IncomingCall.java:94)

Comment: From that logcat, you have a null pointer somewhere in your code causing the Exception. It appears to be from one of your calls to the `Toast.makeText()` method, so you may have a null context.